# Es posible visualizar dos ejes en la Y de un gráfico con diferentes valores?

Tags: javascript, c#, charts

estoy creando un gráfico para visualizar unos datos.
El gráfico lo tengo definido de esta manera :

```
var dataSource = this.datosTest; 
        this.chartOptions = {

            palette: 'Violet',
            dataSource,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: 'Date',
                valueField: 'Value',
                type: 'line',
            },
            seriesTemplate: {
                nameField: 'PPAParameterDesc',
            },
            format: {
                type: "fixedPoint",
                precision: 0
            },
            legend: {
                hoverMode: "excludePoints",
            },
            title: {
                text: `<b>${this.message} ${this.equipment}.</b>\n ${this.startTime}: ${this.startDate} \n ${this.endTime}: ${this.endDate}`,
            },

            valueAxis: {
                valueType: 'numeric',
                grid: {
                    opacity: 0.0,
                },
                label: {
                    customizeText() {
                        return `${this.valueText}`;
                    },
                },
            },
            argumentAxis: {
                type: 'continuous',
                grid: {
                    visible: false,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                },
                argumentAxis: {
                    label: {
                        customizeText() {
                            return `Day ${this.valueText}`;
                        },
                    },
                },
            },

            export: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                customizeTooltip(arg) {
                    return { text: `${arg.seriesName}\n${arg.value}\n${arg.argument.getHours()}:${arg.argument.getMinutes()}:${arg.argument.getSeconds()}` };
                }
            },
            scrollBar: {
                visible: true,
            },
            zoomAndPan: {
                valueAxis: 'both',
                argumentAxis: 'both',
                dragToZoom: true,
                allowMouseWheel: true,
                panKey: 'shift',
            },

            onLegendClick: (e) => {
                console.log(e)
                if (e.target.isVisible()) {
                    e.target.hide()
                } else {
                    e.target.show()
                }
            }
        }
```

El dataSource tiene la siguiente lista de datos :

```
{ "PPAParameterId": "MERCIPPLT001_PPA_Totalizer",
"PPAParameterDesc": "Totalizador caudalímetro CIP",
 "PPAParameterDate": "2023-03-23T03:01:50.3766667Z",
 "PPAParameterValue": "559.781860351562500",
 "PPAParameterType": "F" },
 { "PPAParameterId": "MERCIPPLT001_PPA_Totalizer",
 "PPAParameterDesc": "Totalizador caudalímetro CIP",
 "PPAParameterDate": "2023-03-23T03:01:51.3866667Z",
 "PPAParameterValue": "559.781860351562500",
 "PPAParameterType": "F" },
 { "PPAParameterId": "MERCIPPLT001_PPA_Totalizer",
 "PPAParameterDesc": "Totalizador caudalímetro CIP",
 "PPAParameterDate": "2023-03-23T03:01:52.3866667Z",
 "PPAParameterValue": "559.781860351562500",
 "PPAParameterType": "F" },
{ "PPAParameterId": "MERCIPPLT001_PPA_ReturnTemp",
 "PPAParameterDesc": "Temperatura de Retorno",
 "PPAParameterDate": "2023-03-23T02:59:28.9466667Z",
 "PPAParameterValue": "25.637550354003906",
 "PPAParameterType": "F" },
 { "PPAParameterId": "MERCIPPLT001_PPA_ReturnTemp",
 "PPAParameterDesc": "Temperatura de Retorno",
 "PPAParameterDate": "2023-03-23T02:59:29.9366667Z",
 "PPAParameterValue": "25.639007568359375",
 "PPAParameterType": "F" }
```

Tal cual tengo ahora configurado el grafico, el grafico donde los datos de PPAParameterId": "**MERCIPPLT001_PPA_ReturnTemp**, se va muy alto, ya que sus value, son mucho más grandes que los del **MERCIPPLT001_PPA_ReturnTemp**.

Yo lo que quiero hacer es que por defecto en una escala de y, visualice los datos de temp por ejemplo.
Y en otro eje de y, visualice el rango de totalizer.

He probado creando dos escalas *(sin exito)*, y algunas cosas más como definiendo el alto máximo, pero claro si defino el alto máximo, el grafico de totalizer no lo veo.

En resumen, me gustaria obtener un grafico donde yo todos los datos los vea bien de tamaño, en donde un eje Y haga referencia a temp, y en otro eje Y, los del totalizer.
Es posible de alguna manera?

Comment: Para ser algo más preciso ahora que me doy cuenta, yo a la derecha del grafico, visualizo unos cuadros donde tengo el título de los datos que muestro, en el que si  deselecciono alguno, el eje Y cambia su valor ajustandose automaticamente, es decir si yo en el grafico ahora mismo visualiza de 0 a 600, haciendome pequeño el rango de TEMP, cuando deselecciono el totalizer, el eje Y, se ajusta automaticamente de 0 a 80. Entonces yo quiero esos dos rangos, pero visulizando los datos bién, aunque se superpongan, en el que temp funcione de 0 a 80 por ejemplo y totalizer de 500 a 1000